# file_put_contents not saving text to file

Tags: php

I have a simple code snippet

```
$data = '[' . date('d-m-Y H:i:s') . ']: Operation timeout at URL ' . $this->curlInfo['url'];
print $data;
file_put_contents('/logs/curl_timeout.txt', $data);
```

The print does the following

`[01-08-2014 09:42:05] Operation timeout at URL http://example.com`

I want to save this to the file curl_timeout.txt located under logs. Both the file and the folder have 777 rights. However it is still not working. No text gets saved there. Am I doing sth wrong?

Edit : I also tried opening it first

`fopen('/logs/curl_timeout.txt', 'wb');` But it still doesn't save the text to the file.

Comment: Yes. I created it manually and also gave it 777 rights. 

`chmod -R 777 logs/`

Comment: try: `if (file_put_contents('/logs/curl_timeout.txt', $data) === false) { print "No"; } else { print "done"; }`. If it echoes "done", then I have no idea. if it echoes "No", then there probably is something wrong with the path. EDIT: reading below, if file_get_contents returns false, then your path is wrong. Where is your PHP script located?

Comment: Ye. I just made a `var_dump` on `file_put_contents` and it returns false. However I don't know what could be wrong with the path since the folder logs is under the root folder and right beneath there is the text file `curl_timeout.txt`

Comment: tell us where your php script is located, perhaps you just need to set the path to `../../logs/curl_timeout.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify your file path wrongly: `/logs/curl_timeout.txt', $data);` I mean leading slash,
in that case you should specify absolute path like: /var/www/public_html..` etc..

So use relative path: maybe `../../logs/curl_timeout.txt', $data);` also there may be permissions problem check it also

**Solution would be:**

to define log path `define('LOG_PATH', '/var/www/...log/...')`

than use it like : `file_put_contents(LOG_PATH, $data);`,

also if you have tmp log directory one level up you can try: `file_put_contents(LOG_PATH."../tmp/log/...", $data);`

Comment: Wow. Yep that was the problem. But I thought if I want to go from the root folder I have to use the leading slash. Am I wrong with this one? On a server, if I want to log /tmp/logs/curl_timeout.txt do I there also ignore the leading slashes?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem with the location and file it seems.

Did you check whether that file exists or not ?

Try printing out things from that file using `file_get_contents` first.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer. `file_get_contents` returns `false`. But this only raises more questions. The folder `logs` is in the root folder and right under it there is the file `curl_timeout.txt`. So why does it return false?

Comment: I am sure that location is inaccessible. That's why it returns false when you try to print the things out from the file. Where is your current file saved in ?

Comment: Hey. Yes, the leading slash was the problem. Look @George's answer. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0):

First of all check return value:

```
$result = file_put_contents('/logs/curl_timeout.txt', $data);
var_dump($result);
```

If $result === FALSE then you have a problems. Try to do something like this:

```
$logfile = realpath('./logs/curl_timeout.txt');
$result = file_put_contents($logfile, $data);
var_dump($result);
```